# Laravel 4: Flash script submitting to /controller/method/index.php

Tags: php, flash, laravel-4

I am currently working with some legacy flash files that submit POST data based on some actions.  Problem is I am unable to edit the flash file and flash seems to be submitting to the controller method the flash file is currently on + index.php.

It is fine that its submitting here, I'm just trying to figure out a way to catch it. Everything I attempt continues to return a 'NotFoundHttpException'.

I am currently trying to catch it with:

```
public function postMethod()
{

}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Is the route making it past your htaccess intact? Can you show your routes file? If the route is coming through OK surely you can just match RouteWithFlashFile/index.php to a method in your controller. Something like this:

```
Route::post('RouteWithFlashFile/index.php', 'MyController@processFlash');
```

If that doesnt work, you might have to look at reworking your htaccess to map the route to something else. I will confess this is all speculation as I've never stuck index.php in the middle of a route before.